# Wrong height in view added Dynamically to a container in Android: weight, Linear and Constraint Layouts

Tags: android, kotlin, view, android-layout-weight

## Introduction

I was adding to a Linear Layout the data that I get from an API, so the data is dynamic. It is an app for cryptocurrencies, so for each coin downloaded it draws a new line in a new Layout which is finally added dynamically.

## The containers: ConstraintLayout and inner LinearLayout

I use a ContraintLayout as a first container. Inside it I set up a LinearContainer which will contain the dynamically added views.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coinMarketActivity"
android:background="#131A24"
tools:context="coinmarket.CoinMarket">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/top_bar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/coinMarketCapTitleLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coinMarketCapTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="COIN MARKET CAP"
        android:textColor="#F89D1E"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/coinMarketCapLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/borders"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/coinDataContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/coinMarketCapTitleLinearLayout">
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The container where dynamic views are being added is android:id="@+id/coinDataContainer"

## The dynamic view

This view is inflated from an xml inside the layout folder. Then I add the data I got from the API and add it to the coinDataContainer from the section above. As it's a large XML layout, I will only copy the root element:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="6dp"
android:layout_weight="0.1">
```

As you can see, I'm using the android:layout_weight="0.1" in order to get all the views added with the same height in the screen, having all the space distributed among them. I also set up android:layout_height="0dp" and android:layout_height="wrap_content" with the same result

## The failure

Only the first child added dynamically is being drawn on the screen. Nevertheless, if I add the following code, which is being executed from time to time when all the children have been added, I get that it have 10 children, not 1:

```
var children = _mDataRootView!!.childCount
Log.e("number of children", children.toString())
var firstchild = _mDataRootView!!.getChildAt(0)
Log.e("height of first child", firstchild.measuredHeight.toString())
Log.e("width of first child", firstchild.measuredWidth.toString())
_mDataRootView!!.invalidate() // called to try to redraw without success
```

This is the printed log:

```
08-11 22:43:25.276 4575-4575/app.manu.test E/number of children: 10
08-11 22:43:25.277 4575-4575/app.manu.test E/height of first child: 1013
08-11 22:43:25.277 4575-4575/app.manu.test E/width of first child: 2504
```

And this is how it's being drawn on the screen:

[image: Only one coin is being drawn]

Any idea of what I did wrong?

## More info

If I paste the code of the inflated inner layout into the container, as many times as I want, all the space is being distributed among the views properly, and all them get the same height

Comment: Can you try to set the layout_gravity to center

Comment: @Epig in which layout?

Comment: in the LinearLayout to which the View will be added just an idea

Comment: Thanks @Epig I tried it without success

Comment: You should add the View with a LinearLayout.LayoutParams and in this layoutParams you should set the gravity to center. That worked for me some time ago. But I think you shouldn't use a LinearLayout for that a RecyclerView would be the better choice for this problem.

Comment: @Epig I'll try it, but let me ask a question: apart from setting the gravity to center, should I add something with the layout_weight in LayoutParams ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it!!!
Thanks to @Epig as he gave me the clue I needed.

This is how I was inflating the subview:

```
val coin_martket_item_view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.coin_market_item, null)
```

Then I tried to get the layout param as @Epig told me to set a proper LayoutParam property.

```
val current_params = coin_martket_item_view.layoutParams
```

current_params was always returning null

Then I changed the inflate command to

```
val coin_martket_item_view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.coin_market_item, _mDataRootView, false)
```

providing this way the viewgroup in which they were going to be inflated. Suddenly the layoutParams started to come in the current_params val, and it started to draw 10 coins instead 1, so the issue is solved.

Thank StackOverflow once again!

Comment: It makes me happy that I could help. Just one thing i think you don't need to use layout_weight just set to wrap_content. :)